# Setup and send custom delegate method within init?

Tags: objective-c, ios, delegates, initialization

i have a question about initializing a custom delegate.
Within MyScrollView initWithFrame method, there is the first position where i need to send my delegate. But it´s still unknown there, because i set the delegate within MyCustomView after the initializer.

How can i fix that, so the delegate gets called even within init?
Thanks for your help..

```
MyCustomView.m

 self.photoView = [[MyScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:frame withDictionary:mediaContentDict];
 self.photoView.delegate = self;
//....

MyScrollView.h
@protocol MyScrollViewDelegate
-(void) methodName:(NSString*)text;
@end
@interface MyScrollView : UIView{
 //...
    __unsafe_unretained id <MyScrollViewDelegate> delegate;
}
@property(unsafe_unretained) id <MyScrollViewDelegate> delegate;


MyScrollView.m

-(id) initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame withDictionary:(NSDictionary*)dictionary{ 
self.content = [[Content alloc] initWithDictionary:dictionary];

    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
      //.... other stuff

     // currently don´t get called
     [self.delegate methodName:@"Test delegate"];
}
return self;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am sure you have defined a:

`- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame withDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dictionary;`

Then, just pass the delegate, too:

`- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame withDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dictionary withDelegate:(id<MyScrollViewDelegate>)del;`

**In the Implementation File:**

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame withDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dictionary withDelegate:(id<MyScrollViewDelegate>)del {
    // your stuff...

    self.delegate = del;
    [self.delegate methodName:@"Test delegate"];

}
```

**Use it:**

```
self.photoView = [[MyScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:frame withDictionary:mediaContentDict withDelegate:self];
```

Comment: and darren: Thank you very much for your fast reply. Great community, guys. Now it works perfect. Nice! Have a nice day.

Answer (score 1):

One option might be to pass in your delegate in your custom class's initializer:

```
-(id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame withDictionary:(NSDictionary*)dictionary delegate:(id)delegate 
{ 
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self == nil )
    {
        return nil;
    }
    self.content = [[Content alloc] initWithDictionary:dictionary];
    self.delegate = delegate;
    //.... other stuff

    // Delegate would exist now
    [self.delegate methodName:@"Test delegate"];

    return self;
}
```

Comment: Similar to my answer, just take care to change the `delegate` variable name in the method signature to something other than `delegate`, since that name is used.